# As a documentary photographer, do you pay people you photograph?

Tags: business, street-photography

I wonder if there is **a** best practice or rule to handle the payment of people you photograph for documentary purpose. Especially extreme cases like, e.g. a child living on the street.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no absolute rules but what you do depends on the circumstances.

- In some case you may be *required* to compensate the subject. If you intend to use the photo for commercial purposes,  you will need a model release form. Depending on local-laws, sometimes these *must* include an exchange of value in the contract. This can be monetary payment or something else with perceived value, such as the copy of the photo itself.
- To get a photo for editorial use, you will usually not need a model release but you may still offer payment at your discretion.
- If someone *asks for payment to pose before* you take a photo, I would be wary about the documentary value of the resulting photo.
- If someone *asks for payment after* you take a photo,  it would be at your discretion. Considering the shot was candid and documented what was actually happening, paying would not diminish the documentary nature of the shot, only encourage such behavior. I would avoid it but certainly offering to send a copy would be a nice gesture.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to make money off a photo of a homeless child, you should give that kid something, even if you don't have to.